# Error while creating list item via SOAP-UI

Tags: 2007, soap

I am trying to add new item to list, this is request

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:soap1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <soap1:UpdateListItems>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <soap1:listName> --LIST_GUID_COMES_HERE-- </soap1:listName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <soap1:updates>
         <Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="1" 
            ViewName="--VIEW_GUID_COMES_HERE--">         
          <Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>
            <Field Name='ows_Date'>03/09/2016</Field>           
            <Field Name='ows_Type'>TEST</Field>                     
            <Field Name='ows_Title'>0000</Field>
            </Method> 
          </Batch>
         </soap1:updates>
      </soap1:UpdateListItems>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And this is respond:

```
   <soap:Body>
      <UpdateListItemsResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
         <UpdateListItemsResult>
            <Results>
               <Result ID="1,New">
                  <ErrorCode>0x81020014</ErrorCode>
                  <ErrorText>One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.</ErrorText>
               </Result>
            </Results>
         </UpdateListItemsResult>
      </UpdateListItemsResponse>
   </soap:Body>
```

The error is not very informative. How can identify the issue?

Comment: Are you able to add list item using out of the box New Item Form?

Comment: I can add, some concerns I am not sure which fields are mandatory, the name of fields I took from calling  GetListItems soap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To verify:

- `Name` attribute for `Field` element accepts *field internal name*,
  so make sure the valid field internal name is specified (i guess in
  your case it should be `Date`, `Type` and `Title` instead of `ows_Date`,
  `ows_Type` and `ows_Title`)
- Specify date field value in *ISO format*, for example
  `2016-03-09T00:00:00Z`
- Since `ViewName` attribute of `Batch` element is ignored in
  `UpdateListItems` operation it could be omitted

**Fixed example**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:soap1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <soap1:UpdateListItems>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <soap1:listName>--list guid/name goes here--</soap1:listName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <soap1:updates>
         <Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="1">         
          <Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>
            <Field Name='Date'>2016-03-09T00:00:00Z</Field>           
            <Field Name='Type'>TEST</Field>                     
            <Field Name='Title'>0000</Field>
            </Method> 
          </Batch>
         </soap1:updates>
      </soap1:UpdateListItems>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**How to retrieve field names from List**

Using `GetList` operation you could retrieve field names from `Name` attribute in `Field` element:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soap:GetList>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <soap:listName>--list guid/name goes here--</soap:listName>
      </soap:GetList>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is 'field internal name'? Why when I call GetListItems api it doesn't return me the internal name?

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve the same problem using SOAP-UI. You have to use internal field names which are not the same as you get by GetListItems. The best way to get internal field names is described here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/75ca6fab-56f3-4bf4-aae0-2d29821778a2/how-to-get-internal-names-of-columns-in-sharepoint-lists

Sharepoint puts some ows_ prefix to field names when returning XML containing list. Hard to undestand for me, but it is as it is.